# Create custom web part properties apply to all web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I need to Create a custom WebPart property apply by default to all web part. 
I already make a Custom Toolpart , that work great , but just on my Custom WebPart.

Now I wan't to apply this Toolpart to all WebPart on my sites collection

I think to add a property to the WebPartToolPart(), but a don't know how do this.

Anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Do you want to open always the same ToolPart when editing any WebPart on that SiteCollection?

Comment: Yes , at least have the same common property to all WebPart

Comment: In this case you could do it as described in my answer below. Both methods would work. Please mark as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

A ToolPart is always bound to a WebPart. Therefore, you would need to bind the ToolPart to every WebPart which you are using on the SiteCollection where you need the Property and also you need to add this Property to each WebPart (if the WebParts are different).

Another possible solution could be to write the ToolParts Property to the SiteCollections PropertyBag and enable your WebParts to consume/read the Property in the SiteCollections PropertBag.

But in both cases you would need to modify your WebParts.